# How does std::vector destruct its objects?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I'm trying to implement my own std::vector for sake of practice. Current source code:http://pastebin.com/bE4kjzcb

---

Here is an outline of my class:

1. `Array()` allocate some memory using `malloc()`
2. `push_back(const T &t)` add one element, call `realloc()` if necessary.
3. `~Array()` call `free()` to release memory.

The major issue with this model is, `free()` recycles the memory, but it doesn't call `T`'s destructor(when `T` is a class rather than standard data type).

This could cause severe resource leak when elements inside vectors are objects. My solution to this problem is, call `~T()` **EXPLICITLY** before I `free()` the memory.

The reason I'm using `malloc()` is, I'm trying to utilize `realloc()`. If I use `new` and `delete`, memory usage will peak when reallocing. (The moment when both the new buffer and old buffer are present.)

Q:
Is that a bad design? how does `std::vector` resolve this problem? Is there other flaws in my vector class?

PS:Let's not talk about multithread performances of `malloc()` now.

Comment: If you are using C++, don't use `malloc` and  `free`, use `new`and `delete`

Comment: How do you add element in `push_back`? If you're using placement new, then calling destructor explicitly would be fine.

Comment: You implementation isn't overly safe on the whole. Your `push_back` reinterprets raw uninitialized memory as an object and than assigns to it. Try storing `std::string` in your `Array` and a calamity will surely follow.

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe that `realloc` will not cause a peak in memory usage the same way delete/new combinations would.

Comment: Your assignment operator is flawed in that you change data members before allocating memory.  What if `malloc` returns NULL?  How are you going to "rollback" the changes you made to your object's data members?

Comment: "*The reason I'm using malloc() is, I'm trying to utilize realloc().*" You cannot use `realloc` on storage for types which are not trivially copyable.

Comment: `std::vector` uses an *allocator* that is a template parameter, defaulting to `std::allocator`. As of C++17 and later it will use that allocator via [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct), calling `std::allocator_traits:.construct` to construct an object in specified storage, and `std::allocator_traits::destroy` to destroy an object.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What's inside the black box `allocator_traits`?

Comment: I linked to the docs at cppreference.com, they're generally reliable.

Comment: no, I mean how does `allocator_traits` do its obj? How does it work internally? @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Oh. As the docs explains, `allocator_traits::construct` will use the allocator's `construct` if there is one, and otherwise use a placement `new` expression (the default). And with all standard containers the default allocator is `std::allocator`, whose `construct` function uses a placement `new` expression. So through two levels of defaults it's placement `new`. If you want to use it yourself directly, be sure to include the `new` header, and prefix `new` with a double colon, `::new`, to avoid picking up a class-specific overload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `~T()` is *exactly* how `std::vector` handles the problem.

You do however have a couple of problems:

Firstly, `push_back` needs to use placement new to copy-construct the value into the vector.  You can't just use assignment.

Secondly, you can't call `realloc` - if the object have internal pointers, they are going to end up pointing outside them selves.  You must call `malloc` again, then use placement new to copy-construct the values, then explictly delete all the old values, then call `free` to release the old value.

(Actually, `std::vector` doesn't call `~T()` itself.  Instead it calls the allocator which is responsible for ... *allocating* and deallocating memory.  Internally though, that is how general purpose allocators do it.)

Comment: Not really. `vector` is an allocator-aware container so no mainstream implementation is going to write `~T()`.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper But the default allocator will.

Comment: OK How should I use placement new though? `new (buffer[length]) T()` ?

Comment: If I use placement new, do I still need to assign the allocated object to buffer[length]?(Since the object object is allocated on buffer)

Comment: "If I use placement new, do I still need to assign the allocated object to buffer[length]?" No, `push_back` should call placement `new` with the copy constructor. No assignment.

Comment: "How do I use placement new".  `new(m_end++) T(arg);`  (assuming you have a pointer of type T* which points just past the end of the allocated variables.)

Answer (score 2):

> push_back(const T &t) add one element, call realloc() if necessary.

It is ok as long as `T` is `trivially copiable`,  for example, try to push back double linked lists and after reallcoation take one and iterate backwards - the app will probably crash. the solution is to overload the function twice, one for types which are trivialy copiable, and one for objects that are not.

As opposed to others, I'm quite sorry that the standard containers do not use `realloc` for objects which are trivially copiable. at least on Windows, `realloc` first checks if the current block can hold the new size and if so - it just updates the heap entry, causing huge performance boost (no copying).

> call ~T() EXPLICITLY before I free() the memory.

Yes, this is how the standard allocator does it. assume `size` is the object count, you iterate each one and destruct it manually:

```
for (auto i=0U;i<size;i++){
   data[i].~T();
}
```

Interestingly, C++17 will add `std::destruct` which does exactly that.

***Bonus:***
Using `new[]` and `delete[]` will not help here. usually, dynamic arrays saves *more space* than what they need to achieve capacity ,the extra space is not filled with live objects, only junk.

`new[]` will fill the entire memory with objects. capacity cannot be implemented this way. the array will move/copy the entire objects whenever someone pushes back new elements. so after 1000 `push_back`'s, there will be 1000 reallocations. we want amortized time of `O(log (n))`.

even the standard allocator will call `new(size_t)` or `malloc` and not `new[]`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling to `malloc` and `free`, prefer to use `new` and `delete`. Calling to `delete` will ensure that the instance dtor is called. =)

Comment: I thought about it, but my concern with `new` and `delete` is memory peak when reallocing. (Both the old buffer and new buffer has to be present for a moment so that we can copy data.)

Comment: You wrote your class as a template.  If I give your class a `std::string` or basically any non-POD type, your code will fail using `malloc`.  C++ is not C.

Comment: @KelvinZhang That is something you need if you want to support types that must be deep copied.

Comment: @KelvinZhang So your question is actually about how vector implements reallocation, not about malloc and free right?

Comment: It seems that you're under the impression that realloc retains the memory of the original allocation. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

At the limit it is possible to use *new []* if the default constructor is reserved for *just allocated* objects and if the /move/copy constructors/assignment operators and destructor of T propagate the information *just allocated* or *user object*. The solution in std::vector and its default allocator is nevertheless a far better design.

The construction

```
buffer = new T[capacity];
```

instead of

```
buffer = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(T));
```

and

```
delete [] buffer;
```

instead of

```
free(buffer);
```

will automatically call the destructor of each object as on the example

```
class A {
public:
  ~A() { std::cout << "ok" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  A* a = new A[3];
  delete [] a;
  return 0;
}
```

this code outputs 3 "ok". Then A should contain additional fields and a non default constructor to differentiate allocation from user construction.

Comment: That won't work well when you try to add a single new value to the back of the vector.  You'll have to copy the array *every single time*.

Comment: @MartinBonner I suppose that length can evolve until capacity and that the destructor does nothing on T object created by the default constructor (the ones that are between length and capacity). For reallocation, a new allocation is required with move assignments. Yes std::vector perfectly does the job.

Comment: But the point about capacity is that you don't construct the elements between size() and capacity() - you just allocated the memory.

Comment: @MartinBonner I agree with your comment. The solutions described above and in vector.tcc are more adequate with just an allocation for the elements between size() and capacity().

Answer (score -1):

Here you have an example how it works more or less std::vector:

```
#ifndef __STDVECTOR__
#define __STDVECTOR__

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
    class StdVector{
        private:
            T *buffer;
            unsigned int capacity;
        public:
            //Constructor.
            StdVector(){
                capacity=0;
                buffer=new T[capacity];
            }
            //Copy constructor.
            StdVector(const StdVector &asv){
                int i;
                
                capacity=asv.getCapacity();
                buffer=new T[asv.getCapacity()];
                for (i=0; i<capacity; i++){
                    buffer[i]=asv[i];
                }
            }
            //Destructor.
            ~StdVector(){
                delete []buffer;
            }
            void push_back(T obj){
                StdVector oldSV(*this);
                int i;
                
                capacity++;
                delete []buffer;
                buffer=new T[capacity];
                for (i=0; i<oldSV.getCapacity(); i++){
                    buffer[i]=oldSV[i];
                }
                buffer[i]=obj;
            };
            T getBuffer() const{
                if (capacity==0){
                    throw exception();
                }
                return *buffer;
            };
            T &operator[](int index) const{
                if (index>=capacity){
                    //Out of range.
                    throw exception();
                }
                else{
                    return buffer[index];
                }
            }
            StdVector &operator=(const StdVector &obj){
                capacity=obj.getCapacity();
                delete []buffer;
                buffer=new T[capacity];
                buffer=obj.getBuffer();
                return *this;
            }
            unsigned int getCapacity() const{
                return capacity;
            };
    };
 
#endif

int main(){
    try{
        StdVector<int> test;
        StdVector<string> test2;
        unsigned int i;
        
        test.push_back(5);
        test.push_back(4);
        test.push_back(3);
        test.push_back(2);
        test.push_back(1);
        test.push_back(0);
        test.push_back(-1);
        test.push_back(-2);
        test.push_back(-3);
        test.push_back(-4);
        test.push_back(-5);
        for (i=0; i<test.getCapacity(); i++){
            cout << test[i] << endl;
        }
        test2.push_back("Hello");
        test2.push_back(" ");
        test2.push_back("World");
        test2.push_back(".");
        cout << "---------------" << endl;
        for (i=0; i<test2.getCapacity(); i++){
            cout << test2[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    catch(...){
        cout << "Exception." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

5

4

3

2

1

0

-1

-2

-3

-4

-5

---------------

Hello World.

Maybe i have some error. If you know, say me pls.